# Linux Barcode Printing from Application

Tags: java, linux, jasper-reports

We have an application based on a Linux server.

This generates reports using *iReport*. Previously the reports had worked using the built in *iReport* barcode function, however since rebuilding the server, it's not working anymore.

Does anyone have any ideas?

This was done using barcode4j Code 128.

The error I am seeing in the `jrskdae.log`.

The report will print to screen but will not print directly to the printer

```
[/redprairie/apps/Dispatcher/Appname/Version/server/run/jrtemplates/linescountbyhour.jasper]
java.lang.NullPointerException
at jrtskdae.DashboardReport.run(DashboardReport.java:126)
at    edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:176)
at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:987)
at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:528)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Comment: Well, what error message do you get? "Does not work" is not a valid description in a question.

Comment: I will edit the question shortly. @arkascha

Comment: is the barcode4j.jar included in the project?

Comment: @Endrik not in iReport, I assumed I didnt need to as it is part of iReports built in functionality?